# Concatenate not working in Numbers

Tags: numbers

[Sample numbers file](http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=55986698442835853145)

[image]

B4 contains `CONCATENATE(B2,B3)`

In the file above, I am getting syntax error on B4, despite the formula seems correct. Can anyone reproduce the problem? How can I solve it?

MacBook Air, OS X Yosemite (10.10.5), Numbers version: 3.6.1 (2566)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some locales use semicolon as a separator for parameters in formulae, such as Turkey. You can check this by using a comma after the first parameter, then clicking a cell. If you see a semicolon being inserted alongside the comma you should use a semicolon as a delimiter.

[image]

<strike>This feels like a bug. Copy-pasting the cell shows the syntax error, but copy-pasting the *contents* of the cell (the formula itself) works fine, alongside me retyping the formula. You can provide feedback to Apple here:</strike>

- http://www.apple.com/feedback/numbers.html

Comment: I managed the make it work. Instead of putting comma as the separator of arguments, putting semicolon worked. But were you able to make it work using comma?

Comment: @Utku Yes, what locale is your computer set to?

Comment: I don't know. Where can I check it?

Comment: @Utku System Preferences → Language & Region

Comment: Yep. Region shows Turkey. So this might be the reason?

Comment: @Utku Yep, I've just set my locale to Turkey and I reproduce the problem exactly. I've rewritten my answer.

Comment: I wonder what might be the purpose of such design.

Comment: @Utku, different countries use different characters as special marks. For example, English speaking countries tend to use a comma and a decimal like so: $1,234.56 where as most of Europe (maybe?) would use €1.234,56. By setting a local, apps automatically switch to the correct characters or even currencies. Turkey seems to use semicolons differently to what you expected.

Answer (score -2):

I had better luck using "string1" & "string2".